# How to retrive data from sql table with where condition using get() in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-5

how to retrieve multiple rows from table with where condition using laravel 5.8

I tried with joins but i am not getting data. below provided code is not working in my instance.

I am able to get first row but i am looking for multiple rows.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $event = Event::find($id);
    $speaker = Speaker::where('event_id', '=', $id)->get();
    return view('events-show')->with('event', $event)->with('speaker', $speaker);

}
```

I want to retrieve two tables data using laravel 5.8 and display in view page.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this
```

$speaker=Speaker::join('events','events.id','speakers.event_id')->where('events.id', '=', $id)->get();
 return view('events-show')->with('speaker', $speaker);